# cocos2dx action error: liquid, wave3d and lens3d

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Now I'm following article http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Effects. Examples of the link make errors.
Tested cocos2d-x version is **cocos2d-x 3.2beta0**.

My code:

```
auto bgimage = Sprite::create("top.png");
bgimage->setPosition(visibleSize / 2);

// create a Lens3D action
ActionInterval* lens = Lens3D::create(10, Size(32, 24), Vec2(100, 180), 150);

 // create a Waved3D action
ActionInterval* waves = Waves3D::create(10, Size(15, 10), 18, 15);

// create a sequence an repeat it forever
bgimage->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Sequence::create(waves, lens, NULL)));

this->addChild(bgimage);
```

result logs:

```
Assert failed: GridActions can only used on NodeGrid

Assertion failed!

File: CCActionGrid.cpp
Line: 84
```

What did I mistake? even I remove **liquid action line**, **wave3d** and **lens3d** also show me same error.

Comment: This is a limitation of alpha version:

see here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650122/cant-use-effects-in-cocos2d-x-3-0-alpha-2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650122/cant-use-effects-in-cocos2d-x-3-0-alpha-2

Comment: I'll mention that the Effects docs you linked don't include the NodeGrid note, and it's hard to get Cocos's docs updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion is clear.  You must use NodeGrid if you want use GridActions like Lens3D or Waves3D. If you want use this action, create NodeGride, add your sprite to them, and run action on NodeGrid.

```
auto bgimage = Sprite::create("top.png");
bgimage->setPosition(visibleSize / 2);

// create a Lens3D action
ActionInterval* lens = Lens3D::create(10, Size(32, 24), Vec2(100, 180), 150);

 // create a Waved3D action
ActionInterval* waves = Waves3D::create(10, Size(15, 10), 18, 15);

// create a sequence an repeat it forever
auto nodeGrid = NodeGrid::create();
nodeGrid->addChild(bgimage);
nodeGrid->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Sequence::create(waves, lens, NULL)));

this->addChild(nodeGrid);
```

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that the docs should mention that? Someone should fix that tutorial, 'cause it clearly uses those effects on simple sprites, and not on NodeGrids.